# Facing difficulty in fetching data through lite_json

Tags: substrate-node, api, json, math

Api data

```json
{
  "student": [
    {
      "listing": {
        "price": 54,
      },
    },
 ]
}
```

I’m using below code for fetching data till `listing`:

```rust
let student = match val.ok()? {
  JsonValue::Object(obj) => {
     let (_, v) = obj.into_iter().find(|(k, _)| k.iter().copied().eq("student".chars()))?;
     match v {
        JsonValue::Array(vec) => vec,
        _ => return None,
     }
  },
  _ => return None,
};

for (i, obj) in instances.clone().into_iter().enumerate() {
  let list = match obj.clone() {
     JsonValue::Object(obj_data) => {
        let (_, v) = obj_data.into_iter().find(|(k, _)| k.iter().copied().eq("listings".chars()))?;
        match v {
           JsonValue::Object(list) => list,
           _ => return None,
        }
     },
     _ => return None,
  };

 // ?? price
}
```

**Ques: How to fetch price from `list`?**
**Ques: I'm returning `object` from listing, Is that correct?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```rust
let (_, price_no) = list.into_iter().find(|(k, _)| k.iter().copied().eq("price".chars()))?;
            let p = match price_no {
                JsonValue::Number(list) => list,
                _ => return None,
            };
            let price = p.integer as u32;
```